# expression in one report to see if the value appears in another

Tags: report, vlookup, builder

i have two reports, one report is a report of all the people that i have sent letters out to register for a product, the second report is a report of all the people who have registered for the product after receiving their letter.
both reports contain the same field value of Person_reference

i want to be able to add a column in my first report (the original mailmerge report) that links to the second report that shows if they have registered or not by does the person ref exist in second report if yes then "registered" if no then "not registered" a bit like a vlookup between two sheets on an excel spreadsheet

but i dont know how to link to the other report, any suggestions a greatly appreciated.

if not enough info please let me know what else i need to add

TIA

Kieran